# Pandoc writes date in the wrong timezone to PDF

Tags: datetime, metadata, pandoc

I am in the Eastern time zone, but when I write a date with pandoc to a PDF's metadata, it is off by one hour.

For example if I use `--metadata meta-date="2022:05:17 23:40:50-04:00"` the createdate in the PDF will show `2022:05:17 23:40:50-03:00`.

`timedatectl` shows my correct timezone:

```
    Local time: Wed 2022-05-18 00:05:16 EDT
Universal time: Wed 2022-05-18 04:05:16 UTC
      RTC time: n/a
     Time zone: America/New_York (EDT, -0400)
```

Running `exiftool -createdate="2022:05:17 23:40:50-04:00" somefile.pdf` results in the correct time zone.

What am I missing with what pandoc is doing?

Comment: It looks like PanDoc is adjusting for Daylight Savings for you automatically.  Try testing out a date such as `2022:01:01 00:00:00` and see if it writes the date as is.

Comment: Good suggestion, StarGeek. It looks like the command:
` --metadata  date-meta `
is not being used at all.
` pandoc --metadata date-meta="2022:01:01 00:00:00"  test-doc.md --pdf-engine=xelatex --template=$HOME/.local/share/pandoc/templates/pdf-template.tex -s -o test.pdf ` 
produced a date stamp in the PDF of 
` 2022:05:18 14:30:26-03:00 '
Interestingly, changing the pdf engine did fix the timezone, but it did not use the value of date-meta.
`pandoc --metadata date-meta="2022:01:01 00:00:00" --pdf-engine=pdflatex  test-doc.md -s -o test.pdf `
produced 
` 2022:05:18 14:40:04-04:00 `

Comment: My guess is date-meta doesn't work in my version of pandoc for writing to PDFs. I am using:
`pandoc 2.9.2.1 `

Comment: Thanks @tarleb for fixing my question! Appreciated.

Comment: Set  the environment variable `SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH=$(date +%s)`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/229605 for details.

Comment: I created a docker container (Alpine with pandoc) so I could use the latest version, `pandoc 2.18` and in each case the actual file create date was used instead of any value in `--metadata date-meta=` Also in both pandoc versions, the `xelatex` always has the wrong time zone (one hour early), but `pdflatex` and `lualatex` have the timezone right.  I used did some test with epoch format dates (`date +%s`), but it did not affect the results. I know I must be missing something, but until I figure it out, I'll use `exiftool` to set the create date.

Comment: You should take note of the fact that exiftool uses an incremental update technique when writing to pdfs.  See [exiftool's PDF tags page](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/PDF.html) and (Foxit's Incremental Updates in PDF files page) for details.  Re-linearizing the file as detailed on the exiftool page will make the changes permanent.